# db in db.collection.... is undefined, and I can't figure out why

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my server.js file. In my get '/' route, I keep getting db is not defined. I am trying to post retrieve documents from a mongodb collection, and eventually have the user be able to query the database using a document key:value. Any thoughts?

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds061355.mlab.com:61355/db');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});



app.get('/:name', (req, res) => {
    var cursor = db.collection('materials').find();
    db.collection('materials').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Running app.js on 3000');
});
```

Comment: Where do you defined `db` variable?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't have `db` defined anywhere so it has to be `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

After the call to the `connect` method, you must use the `connection` property of the `mongoose` object. And you should also listen for events like `error` in case of an error and `open` to know when the connection is established successfully. You should proceed only once the connection is `open`. So your code should be something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds061355.mlab.com:61355/db');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log("Connected Successfully.");

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    app.get('/:name', (req, res) => {
        var cursor = db.collection('materials').find();
        db.collection('materials').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Running app.js on 3000');
    });
});
```